# Merge str value in Hadoop Reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, hashmap, google-cloud-platform

My mapper class will output key-value pairs like:

```
abc 1 
abc 2 
abc 1
```

And I want to merge the values and calculate the occurrence of same pair in reducer class using `HashMap`, the output is like:

```
abc 1:2 2:1
```

But my output result is:

```
abc 1:2:1 2:1:1
```

It feels like there are additional Strings concatenated with the output, but I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
Text combiner = new Text();
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

@Override
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
                    Context context
                   ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    HashMap<Text, Integer> result = new HashMap<Text, Integer>();
    for (Text val : values) {
      if(result.containsKey(val)){
          int newVal = result.get(val) + 1;
          result.put(val, newVal);
      }else{
          result.put(val, 1);
      }
    }
    for(Map.Entry<Text, Integer> entry: result.entrySet()){
       strBuilder.append(entry.getKey().toString());
       strBuilder.append(":");
       strBuilder.append(entry.getValue());
       strBuilder.append("\t");
    }
    combiner.set(strBuilder.toString());
    context.write(key, combiner);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this code an it looks ok. The most likely reason you're getting output like this is because you're running this reducer as your combiner as well, which would explain why you're getting three values. The combine does the first concatenation, followed by the reduce which does a second.

You need to make sure a combiner **isn't** being configured in your job setup.

I would also suggest you change your code to make sure you store new versions of the `Text` values in your HashMap, remember Hadoop will be reusing the objects. So you should really be doing something like:

`result.put(new Text(val), newVal);`

or change your HashMap to store Strings, which is safe since they're immutable.